# Plot with descriptive statistics in each point of the serie

Tags: plotting

I have  a list similar to the next, but with 361 arrays lists instead of 3:

```
list={{1,2,1,2,3,5},{1,2,3,4,3,3},{3,4,2,5,4,6}}
```

And I would like to make a plot showing the mean, standard deviation, max and min for each array, something similar to a serie of box-plots. How can I make this?

I already made this plot calculating the mean and standard deviation, but I would like something better
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
fivestats = Map[Through@{Min, Mean @ # - StandardDeviation @ # &, Mean, 
       Mean @ # + StandardDeviation @ # &, Max} @ # &];

list2 = fivestats @ list;

TableForm[list2, TableHeadings -> {{"data 1", "data 2", "data 3"} , {"Min", 
    "Mean-StdDev", "Mean", "Mean+StdDev", "Max"}}]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose @ list2, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed, Automatic, Dashed, Automatic}, 
 Filling -> {2 -> {4}}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Min", "Mean-StdDev", "Mean", "Mean+StdDev", "Max"}]
```

[image]

In versions 12.0+, you can use [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html)

```
list3 = Map[Through[{Min, Mean, Max, 
     Around[Mean @ #, StandardDeviation @ #]&} @ #] &]@list;

ListLinePlot[Transpose @ list3, IntervalMarkers -> "Bands"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found that ErrorBar and ErrorBarListPlot are very useful for this sort of thing.
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]